# @Guarded not validating @NotNull constructor fields

Tags: java, bean-validation, oval

I'm trying to use Oval 1.84 for getting around some validation constraints without boilerplates. The validation works when I mark fields with @NotNull (javax.validation.constraint and net.sf.oval.validator).

But doesn't work in the case of implementing constarints to method and constructor parameters.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I think the answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859895/hibernate-validator-method-or-constructor-validation/43991633#43991633 may help if someone else comes across this post.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter validation requires the use of some method invocation intercepting bytecode. OVal provides ready to use implementations for AspectJ and Spring AOP.

### With AspectJ

How to use it with AspectJ is documented in detail at http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#programming-by-contract

### With Spring AOP

The usage with Spring AOP is outlined in the test case at
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/oval/code/trunk/src/test/java/net/sf/oval/test/integration/spring/SpringAOPAllianceTest.java

In Spring you need to configure your beans for which you want to have method parameter validation, e.g.:

```
<bean id="myService" class="com.example.MyService" />
```

And an Invocation Interceptor:

```
<bean id="ovalGuardInterceptor" class="net.sf.oval.guard.GuardInterceptor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="false" />
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>ovalGuardInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <!-- the next line tells which beans you want to use validation for -->
    <property name="beanNames" value="myService" />
</bean>
```